# WordPress export table getting error - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Tags: wordpress

Hi to all WordPress experts. I would like to ask why I am getting **error Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent**  the **fputcsv()** is correctly outputting  but not writing on csv and no force download happens. Please help me thanks.

```
 class mycsv{ 

     function generate_csv(){

     global $wpdb;

     $sql = "SELECT * from _mamahota_activity  WHERE activity_date = '2016-08-07' ";
      $MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results($sql);


      $csv_fields=array();
      $csv_fields[] = 'Activity Date';
      $csv_fields[] = 'Name';
      $csv_fields[] = 'Activity Name';
      $csv_fields[] = 'Email Address';
      $csv_fields[] = 'Phone No.';

      $output_handle = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

      header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv'); 


     foreach ($MyQuery as $Result) {
      $leadArray = (array) $Result; // Cast the Object to an array
      fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
    }
    exit;
 }
}
```

Comment: if I put ob_start() on first line after php tag it will work it download but there is a html tag inside. please need help thanks

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the code that calls `mycsv::generate_csv()`?

Comment: hi Hobo is that for rails? Im using php wordpress

Comment: AS the error (actually, just a notice) specifies which *line* the error is on, as well as *which line* has already sent the headers, it would be very useful to share that information - which line(s) are causing the problem(s)?

Comment: hi cale_b  this the error shown Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/activity/wp-includes/functions.php:3718) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mahota/wp-content/plugins/activity/activity-csv.php on line 7

Comment: Any idea why this error occurs? Thanks

Comment: is there any echo or prints before calling this funtion?

Comment: Hi vel there is no print or echo

Comment: @coolshox, seems your code working fine in my end.

Comment: any html tag before that class?

Comment: hi vel there is a html tag its a form 
<form method="POST" action="">
 <div class="wrap">
     <h2>Export Sunday Walk Activity Participant List</h2>
     <hr>
     <div>
       <div class="alignleft actions">
          <label>Date</label>
         <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="date" value=""/>
          <input type = "submit" name ="submit" value = "export" class = "button-primary">
         </div>
        <br class="clear">
      </div>
  </div>
</form>

Comment: add this html tags after mycsv class and try.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $csv = new mycsv;    
    $csv->generate_csv();

  }

Comment: @vel it only ouput textfile not csv file and dowload

Comment: Anyone can help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue. I add ob_start() and ob_clean

```
add ob_start()
 class mycsv{ 

 function generate_csv(){

 global $wpdb;

 $sql = "SELECT * from activity  WHERE activity_date = '2016-08-07' ";
  $MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
  ob_clean();
  $csv_fields=array();
  $csv_fields[] = 'Activity Date';
  $csv_fields[] = 'Name';
  $csv_fields[] = 'Activity Name';
  $csv_fields[] = 'Email Address';
  $csv_fields[] = 'Phone No.';

  $output_handle = fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

  header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv'); 


 foreach ($MyQuery as $Result) {
  $leadArray = (array) $Result; // Cast the Object to an array
  fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
}
exit;
}
}
```